# Average case complexity of bubble sort vs insertion sort

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, sorting

This site already has some questions on this topic but I am confused after reading some of the answers.

[Evaluating the average time complexity of a given bubblesort algorithm.](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/20/evaluating-the-average-time-complexity-of-a-given-bubblesort-algorithm)

In the above link, answer by "Joe" says that number of swaps in bubble sort on average is same as number of inversions on average which is (n)(n-1) / 4.

However, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17270628/insertion-sort-vs-bubble-sort-algorithms says that in bubble sort average number of swaps  is $n^2 / 2$ and in insertion sort it is $n^2 /4$ and that's the reason for insertion sort being better than bubble sort.

Which one is correct? Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a big difference between the [first answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/20/evaluating-the-average-time-complexity-of-a-given-bubblesort-algorithm) you quote, on this site, and the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17270628/insertion-sort-vs-bubble-sort-algorithms) you quote, on stackoverflow: while the answer on cs.se contains an argument, the answer on stackoverflow just states the result without any explanation. This means that you can *verify* the answer on cs.se: you can check whether the proof is correct, and whether the result answers your question. In contrast, there is no way to know whether the answer on stackoverflow is correct or not, apart from trusting its poster.

This highlights a general difference between *programmers* and *computer scientists*. Programmers just want to know the answer, and generally don't care whether it's correct or not. Computer scientists, in contrast, want to see some evidence: a proof if one is available, or results of experiments (or both, in some communities).

Two more proofs of the formula $\frac{n(n-1)}{4}$ can be found on [math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453686/what-is-the-expected-number-of-swaps-performed-by-bubblesort) and on [cs.se](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2630/expected-number-of-swaps-in-bubble-sort). See if any of these convince you of this formula. You have to check both the *statement* (whether you are counting the correct expectation) and the *proof*.

Another thing you can do is experimentally determine the veracity of these proofs. This would entail programming both algorithms, and running them on many different arrays of length $n$ for various values of $n$, thus estimating the number of swaps.

A user on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42810832/number-of-swaps-and-comparisons-in-bubble-selection-insertion-and-quick-sorts) did a simpler experiment which suggests that the number of swaps is the *same* in bubble sort and inversion sort (at least for the user's version of these algorithms, quoted in the question). This would imply, of course, that the average number of swaps is the same in both algorithms.

Comment: So you say that on average, both insertion and bubble sort perform equally ? If not, can you give an example where bubble sort outperforms insertion sort?

Comment: My answer is only about the number of swaps (or comparisons). Besides, I think I've given you enough tools to explore this question on your own.

Comment: To be honest, the links or tools which you have given are the ones which OP had already discovered. (Regarding the no of comparisons).

Comment: @SagarP Are you sure? The user gave 2 links, and I gave 3 more.

Comment: Yes, out of those 3, 2 of them show the number of comparisons which OP already knows. I think it would have been better if you could have added how is insertion sort actually better than bubble sort.

Comment: @SagarP That's not what the OP asked. But you are welcome to add your own answer.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I was able to come up with few examples where insertion sort has fewer comparisons than bubble sort and also some cases where they both have same comparisons. But I am not able to prove that insertion sort will always have comparisons **less than or equal to**  that of bubble sort. Can you please help me or edit the answer ?

Comment: It seems like you have a different question. You should ask it separately. It's also a good idea to describe what *you* call insertion sort and bubble sort - there are several variants of these algorithms.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus ok, https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/84504/proving-number-of-comparisons-in-insertion-and-bubble-sort